# Mass ID3 tag editor like vorbistagedit?

Tags: command-line, mp3, music, id3, vorbis

My favorite tool for batch editing of vorbis comments is vorbistagedit. I can do `vorbistagedit *.ogg` and it lets me edit the metadata in all my ogg files at once in my favorite editor (emacs).

I'm wondering if there is a tool that works in a similar fashion for id3 tags?

I could see it opening up a file that looked something like:

```
: file1.mp3
+ file1.mp3
TIT2=Title
TPE1=Artist
TALB=Album

: file2.mp3
+ file3.mp3
...
```

And I could add/edit tags as I see fit, and when I close out the $EDITOR, it writes the tags back to the files.

It wouldn't have to work exactly like that, but I think that would be my ideal. Anything would be easier than a bunch of BASH `for` loops with `id3v2`.

If nothing like it exists, I might end up writing my own that uses the eyeD3 library.

And please don't bother suggesting EasyTag. It's a great program, but I'm looking for something that doesn't require a GUI.

**P.S.** For those who don't want to bother reading the comments below, I simply modified vorbistagedit to support id3 tags in mp3 files. The modified script can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/goodevilgenius/tagedit).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`vorbistagedit` is just a shellscript which wraps around `vorbiscomment`. You could enhance that script to use one of the mp3 tag editors like `mp3tag` from http://www.mp3tag.de/en/ or an other one with batch facilities.

Comment: Brilliant! I didn't realize that! I'll do exactly that. That will make writing a new one much easier.

Comment: @DanJones Please report back on your solution if you decide to rewrite the script (or solve it any other way). Others might benefit from it.

Comment: I've already started rewriting it. Once it's working, I'll put it on GitHub and put the link here.

Comment: https://github.com/goodevilgenius/tagedit